# CSS3 Transform has random z-index/depth

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, css-transforms

Perhaps I have found a Bug in CSS3, or it's a simple mistake...

Here is the page I'm working on:
http://robocup2014.herokuapp.com/views/view/52e9bbb2e22d2402003d1ef1

I might not be able to show the error, because its behavior is completely random... But here is what happens:

The flag should be ALWAYS behind that purple layout. However, it is sometimes on top, sometimes below. Sometimes it is on top and goes below (without any code running on javascript), or perhaps it goes on top, out of the blue. Sometimes when it animates, it is below, and then goes on top on the end of the animation, but later, it goes below.

What I mean is: It's RANDOM, and it's a boring bug, without any pattern. (I have counted time, counted animations iterations...).

So, does anyone know how to prevent this? Here is a image, in case in your window it doesn't bug. (It happens on Safari and Chrome)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Off-topic, but I want to let you know that these 2 flags overlap in smaller screens such as mine. You might want to adjust some things based on the user's screen width.

Comment: @Joeytje50 This will be shown in 30-50inches TV's. I will try to do some script to change the 'zoom' automatically, but for now try to 'zoom-out' it a bit

Comment: @IvanSeidel You should include the code in the question itself in order to help future readers, because the linked page could change.

Comment: You should include the code in question, as @IvanSeidel says. Also, it would be very nice if *isolate* the code of the tab in question (out of the other 6 animated tabs

Comment: @vals and @Oriol , It's hard to simulate this error on `jsfiddle`. It's very specific, and I haven't been able to simulate it egain... I'm without any options here

Comment: At this point I do not even care about a `jsfiddle` it would just be nice to see some the isolated code. Can you please edit with the code in the question so that we can see what the issue seems to be?

Comment: Try CSS3 perspective.

Answer (score 4):

I had to figure out the same problem recently and the `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` solution didn't worked for me.

The fact is that z-index just stack elements in a 2D world, so since you use 3D transformations z-index cannot apply.

So the real question is IMHO :

**How to stack elements in a 3D world ?**

Answer :

*Use the Z axis !*

This is simple as it, but not intuitive because of browser's rendering. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCxak/2/) to try to illustrate it. I tried to  match as much as possible to your situation, which is hard, just by having your code through your page. In this fiddle, you have four (2 on 2 lines) flags like. I made 2 other div (score) representing an element that should be over the others. The first line is buggy, while the second isn't.

To see the bug, you can simply move your cursor over an element, knowing that cursor is css `pointer` on the flag, and css `col-resize`. You can see that when you hover the green element from left to right, your cursor changes.

I made some schemas (yes, they are ugly ;)) to illustrate the problem. Here are our elements represented as they should be (to my mind) by the browser :

[image: blue is over green!]

I think the problem is now easier to see. On the right, the green element in over the blue, this is what we want. But, on the left, the `rotateY()` caused the blue element to "go out of the screen", passing over the green element. See this view "from above" if this is not really clear :

[image: view from above]

We can think that the blue element go out of the screen by half of its size. So, the solution I found (I think this is probably NOT the best solution, but this work, and is cross-browser since you use browser's own implementations of `transform`, such as `-webkit-transform`.

Scroll to the second line of the fiddle, hover the green element, and see that the cursor stays the same BUT we lose totally the cursor `pointer` over the blue element. I "just" translated the blue element on the Z axis to -10000px, to be sure that it is far away and wont "go out of the screen" when it will rotate. Note the order which is important here, first the translation `translate3d(0, 0, -10000px)`, then the perspective and finally the rotation giving it : `transform: translate3d(0, 0, -10000px) perspective(1200px) rotateY(-45deg);`. As you can see on my last schema (from above) :

[image: blue element is now far away !]

The blue element is now far away, and wont go over the green one. **The last problem we can see**, is that if the blue element is larger than 10000 pixels, it will go over the green element again.

In conclusion, I am sure this solution is more a workaround than a *real* solution. But it was usefull in my case, and I hope I wont fall away from your initial problem and this will  help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for your (complete) answer. However, I tought about that in the begining, and after reading a lot, I found out that the 3D canvas, is actually handled as a 2D element in HTMl, it's like an rendered image, not actually an '3D object'. Because of that, Z-index should work, even with different Z-Index in different contexts, right? Also, Why is it so random, and why it stops happening after, lets say, 1 minute? And also, why isn't only half of the 'scores' div cropped? Thanks =)

Comment: @Ivan Hi, I think that elements are actually rendered (in the meaning 'shown') like 2D elements. But I saw the contrary of what you said, that z-index cannot work, because it is made to work in a '2D world', so I came to my solution which worked in my case. Concerning your random  problem, I think I saw that transitions between your 'pages' are random, so cannot these random be linked ? And I think 'score' divs are totally cropped maybe because of another div on top? Many though in my post but it is hard to isolate the problem just having your page as a reference. Pleased to help you. :)

Comment: Z-index might not work, but `should` work because stacking 3D layers is actually rendering them as 2D, and showing in DOM. But, since CSS3 is pretty new, there might be some problems... I will work on that and see what I can fix, nevertheless, if it keeps happening, I think I will just have to wait the randomness to stop after some secconds

Comment: Yeah I agree that it **should**. Well I wish you luck and please give updates if you find a solution. :)

Comment: I didn't have time to test it yet, but I think your answer will solve it by applying a 3D transform to the "score" div, and also, thanks for doing such an elaborate answer

Comment: I hope it'll work ! Thank you too for taking time to test my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the browser versions with us? I'm not seeing it on the most recent versions of Chrome or Safari or Firefox.

It might be related to this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61824

You could try adding this to the flat items:

`transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`

That way they will all be treated at 3D elements and fewer chances of seeing a bug.

Also, you should be using all the browser prefixes. I'm not seeing the transform on Firefox at all, so I can't tell if it is an issue on that browser, as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but if you look at classes `.flag` and `.flag.left` or `.flag.right`, you will see that I have implemented all browsers kits... They are all initially translated, and the bug, seems to `learn` with time, so that after a few minutes, it dosn't happens egain! It's really crazy.

Comment: They arent 3D transformed in the latest FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the bug in Chrome, Safari or Firefox.
I have found a similar question in stackoverflow that may apply to your case ([Complex Webkit Bug? Relative Position + Z-Index + Overflow Hidden + CSS3 Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949782/complex-webkit-bug-relative-position-z-index-overflow-hidden-css3-transfo))

I would suggest though to use some Javascript before firing the sliding event in order to calculate z-index and apply a higher value on the "purple blocks" or even discard CSS transitions at all and use Javascript transitions only.